# How to highlight only unpublished nodes in views result

Tags: 6, theming, views

I have a node view with bulk operation style which is available for only admin role.
I would like to hilight only the unpublished nodes. It doesn't matter if just one of the fields or whole row of those nodes are hilighted.

I suppose I need to add special css class to unpublished nodes but how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your views add fields:

1. Node: Published, options "Label" empty, tick "Exclude from display",
   "Output  format" choose "True/False"
2. Node: Title, option "Rewrite the output of this field" write `<span
   class="[status]">[title]</span>`
3. Make css class ".false {color:red;}" for "unpublished" in your theme .css file

make 2 and 3 to your vbo fields, add "Node: Published", and rearrange to be first top field

Comment: thanks it worked for me, small correction in css class it is ".False {color:red;}".